# Can a toilet be moved 6 inch to the right?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I want to move my toilet over horizontally by 6 inches. Is there an "S" shape pipe piece I can use to connect my existing plumbing to my toilet?

Is there any other simple solution to getting this done? Anything that is shy of having to re-plumb the 4 inch pipe going to the bowl is desirable.

Here is some context on the toilet project... the toilet in question is in a 2nd floor bathroom. Since I am taking things down to the studs I can pull up the sub floor and expose the pipe. The pipe is plastic.

Comment: You might run into trouble depending on where the joists are, it's hard to tell until you pull up the floor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you strip down the floor, it is an easy job to extend the 4 inch PVC to the new closet flange.  You have to have a new closet flange anyway, so a coupling, 6 inches of pipe, a new elbow and you're in business.

Re-plumb it and avoid a lot of grief in your life, like leaks coming down through the ceiling. The Micky Mouse adapter in the last answer is completely unacceptable for toilet waste.