# Can a toilet on concrete slab be moved about 4 1/2 inches?

Tags: bathroom, toilet

My toilet is situated such that it doesn't allow much room to get in and out of the shower. I'd like to move it back to the wall as close as possible, to allow more space. The toilet is on concrete slab. Is this possible? I saw this similar question (http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6123/can-a-toilet-be-moved-6-inch-to-the-right) was asked but that is for a toilet over subfloor. Also, I know there are different sized toilets but is the distance from the hole on bottom of toilet to the back of the toilet a standard size?

Answer (score 11):

In the US, the typical toilet rough in size is 12", which I believe goes from the toilet bolts (center of the drain) to the studs (so subtract 1/2" for drywall). You can also find toilets made for 10" and 14" rough ins. But, to get more clearance, the easiest thing to do is swap out the style of toilet from an elongated bowl to a round bowl. If you're a man visiting the library, it means you have less space to hang free, but it gives you a lot more space to get around the bathroom.

To answer your first question, you can move the drain, but it involves taking a jackhammer to the concrete. Not a fun project if you don't like messes.

Comment: We ended up going the jackhammer route. To make matters worse the plumber discovered a y-split where he was going to attach the new pipe, so he had to do extra work there. Overall it was the right decision. Cost $550. When the plumber filled the concrete it was about 1/8" higher than the rest of the slab. I thought it'd be better to be lower than higher but that's what he did.

Answer (score 2):

Build a platform for the toilet to set on.  It must be tall enough so that the drain can be redirected towards the existing drain hole and maintain the correct slope.

Comment: Interesting idea but I'm not sure how it would be possible to keep the platform hidden

Comment: @Andrew - If you really need to 'hide' such a platform, you'd have to basically platform the whole room, so that's not much of a win. If you think about it, you can probably integrate such a platform into your decor without it being a problem, but it clearly is going to be visible.